# sorting a bed file by a column and general number

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a bed file like this:

```
#chrom  start   end     value
chr1    11323785        11617177        0.862170087976540
chr1    12645605        13926923        0.934891485809683
chr1    14750216        15119039        0.945945945945946
chr1    18102157        19080189        0.895174708818636
chr1    29491029        30934636        0.892526250772082
chr1    33716472        35395979        0.911901081916538
chr2    13108570        15600747        0.902084152575698
chr2    15694926        17648720        0.887029288702929
chr2    17724731        18378756        0.000837797619047
chr2    19442702        19551715        0.304347826090000
chr2    20745595        21842850        0.000430434255552
chr3    59553227        59708848        1
chr3    59790383        61504477        0.772413793103448
chr3    62167230        62508631        0.230046948357259
chr3    62589695        63775476        0.979970326409496
chr3    64469064        65348951        0.980019980019980
chr3    66972860        67511514        0.850828729281768
chr6    84151925        85317754        0.900999091734787
chr6    85428902        86109751        0.961119751166407
chr6    86456610        87828399        0.963746223564955
chr6    88048916        88236474        0.886227544910183
chr6    88568774        89535038        0.976602238046796
chrX    123088093       128394210       0.855213637369936
chrX    130635879       133327791       0.895311949242157
chrX    134061433       134880328       0.878120411160059
chrX    135187116       135597436       0.940133037694013
```

My goal is to use sort to 'sort' as a general number (1e-3 < 0.05).
I try:

```
sort -g -k4 filename
sort -g -k4 filename

awk '{print $4}' small.bed | sort -g
```

However I didn't get what I was ask for. The last one worked fine sorting the float values, however I only printed the fourth col.
Any tip?

Thank you for your time.

Paulo

Comment: Try with `-k 5`, not `-k 4` !

Comment: Please show example input that also contains numbers like `1e-3`.

Comment: `sort -g -k4 filename` will sort your float column correctly. The question is unclear.

Comment: the exercise was to sort the bed files according to the specified task. Here I just put a toy ex once the file is bigger. The task is sorting the file accord to a value and through a certain column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a numeric sort?  Any non-numeric keys will evaluate to zero, so you don't need to clip off the '# header' line.

```
$ sort -n -k4,4 filename
#chrom  start   end     value
chr2    20745595        21842850        0.000430434255552
chr2    17724731        18378756        0.000837797619047
chr3    62167230        62508631        0.230046948357259
chr2    19442702        19551715        0.304347826090000
chr3    59790383        61504477        0.772413793103448
chr3    66972860        67511514        0.850828729281768
chrX    123088093       128394210       0.855213637369936
chr1    11323785        11617177        0.862170087976540
chr6    88048916        88236474        0.886227544910183
chr2    15694926        17648720        0.887029288702929
chr1    29491029        30934636        0.892526250772082
chr1    18102157        19080189        0.895174708818636
chrX    130635879       133327791       0.895311949242157
chr6    84151925        85317754        0.900999091734787
chr2    13108570        15600747        0.902084152575698
chr1    33716472        35395979        0.911901081916538
chr1    12645605        13926923        0.934891485809683
chr1    14750216        15119039        0.945945945945946
chr6    85428902        86109751        0.961119751166407
chr6    86456610        87828399        0.963746223564955
chr6    88568774        89535038        0.976602238046796
chr3    62589695        63775476        0.979970326409496
chr3    64469064        65348951        0.980019980019980
chr3    59553227        59708848        1
```